# How to thread safe and make a parallel tasks, parallelization and thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, thread-safety

I want to make my code optimize and also safe async thread in c#. The code I have currently which redundant enough to use twice Task.WhenAll, am planning to use only one and make sure the task is thread safe and parallel as well.

This is my current implementation which i think the best way for me at the moment but anyone can suggest more optimized version would be appreciated as well.

```
 var tasks = new List<Task>();
// check for null reference for the items
if (results != null && results.items != null)
{
    // multithreaded might not be supported by the post request
    // changed to single thread for loop
    for(var i = 0; i < results.items.Count; i++) {
        var request = new PostAutoActionExecRequestJson()
        {
            ActionID = model.A_ID,
            Changes = new List<object>(),
            History = new HistoryJson()
            {
                Comment = model.Comment,
                DatastoreID = results.items[i].d_id,
                ItemID = results.items[i].i_id
            },
            RevNo = results.items[i].rev_no,
        };

        tasks.Add(services.PostAutoActionExecAsync<ExpandoObject>(request, token));
    }

    tasks.Add(CalculateNextExecution(model));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The pasted code should run asynchronously and finish the task at the same time.

Kindly let me know please.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Enough to basically copy, paste, and compile your code?

Comment: this is the current code i can show but i just to confirm if this is ok? i mean the code currently is ok or need more enhanced

Comment: When I try to run this code I have 12 compile errors. I'd like enough code to copy, paste, and compile without errors.

Comment: `results`, `PostAutoActionExecRequestJson`, `model`, `services`, `token`, and `CalculateNextExecution` are all not defined.